# How to send some ether to contract when trying to change the price of token?

Tags: solidity, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I made an Ethereum smart contract in Solidity where a user can buy/sell/transfer tokens. In the contract, the admin can change the token price using changePrice(uint256 price) function. I want to make sure that the contract has sufficient ethers when executing this function because contracts might lack ethers to send to users when they want to sell their tokens to contract.

I wrote the following code. It changes the price of token but fails to suffice the balance of contract. I am sure the number of tokens sold (tokensSold) are being tracked correctly.

What part should I repair?

Thanks in advance.

```
  function changePrice(uint256 price) public payable returns (bool success) {
      require(msg.sender == admin, "Only the admin is authorised to change the price of Token.");
      
      if (address(this).balance < price.mul(tokensSold)) {
        uint256 fundsNeeded = (price.mul(tokensSold)).sub(address(this).balance);
        require(msg.sender.balance >= fundsNeeded, "Can't change price: your balance seems insufficient to send funds to the contract.");
        address(this).transfer(fundsNeeded);
      }
      
      require(address(this).balance >= price.mul(tokensSold), "Contract has insufficient funds for the price to be changed.");
      
      tokenPrice = price;
      
      emit Price(price);
      
      return true;
  }
```

Comment: A token cannot transfers funds from another account. It only has access to its own balance. This code `address(this).transfer(fundsNeeded)` transfers funds to itself.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. Is there any way to send ether to contract internally without manually entering the value in "VALUE" field in Remix?

Comment: No, it for ether it is not possible. You can use WETH = ether wrapped as ERC20 token, with ERC20 owner calls approve and contract calls transferFrom. Or you can ask for more ether and return the surplus to the sender.